# How to run a function when the cd command is run

Tags: shell, zsh

I am kind of new to Linux and am just learning to make the computer do the work that I want.

So my wish is that whenever I use the `cd`
command, I want it to change directory and then list all the files present in them. If there are no arguments passed, I want the `pwd` command to run.

This is what I have done so far.

```
function cd {
        if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
                pwd
        else
                cd "$1"; ls -l
        fi
}
```

When I run this, it works fine when there are no arguments passed and it runs the pwd command. However, when I pass an argument, it does not display anything and it closes the terminal, which is'nt what I want.

When I changed the function name to ca though, and ran `ca`, it worked as expected.

Why is this so? Are there a list of aliases I am not allowed to use? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recursively call your function instead of calling the `cd` builtin.

In ZSH the `builtin` command can be used to execute a builtin explicitly suppressing shell function lookup. This is exactly what you need to implement a function that has the same name as a shell builtin

```
function cd {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        pwd
    else
        builtin cd "$1" ; ls -l
    fi
}
```

This applies to BASH as well.

### Regarding the `command` builtin

In BASH you could use the `command` builtin to execute an external command or a builtin. That is where BASH is different from ZSH as in ZSH `command` executes external commands only.

**Only in BASH**

`command cd` works the same as `builtin cd` (assuming `/bin/cd` does not exist)

**In ZSH**

`command cd` would probably fail with `cd: command not found` unless `/bin/cd` exists

Answer (score 2):

If it exists, `chpwd_functions` is an array of function names, each of which will be called, in order, whenever the working directory changes. In your case, it could be used as follows:

```
foo () {
  if [[ $PWD == $HOME ]]; then
    pwd
  else
    ls -l
  fi
}

chpwd_functions+=(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "cd" command in Bash can take options, so using just $1 will drop the directory name.  This passes everything:

```
function cd {
        if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
                pwd
        else
                cd "$@"; ls -l
        fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue having switched from bash to zsh. Example function...

```
go() {
      if [[ $@ == "code" ]];    then command cd "$CODE"; 
}
```

The solution for me was to  1. prefix my function with `function` and 2. replace `command` with `builtin`

```
function go() {
    if [[ $@ == "code" ]];      then builtin cd "$CODE"; 
}
```